# raw github token value in url R github api

Tags: r, github

How does one programatically get the `raw.github.com` token value in the url when looking at the raw option on the webste. I.e can you get that token value from the `api.github.com` api provided?

What I am in reference to is the same as what was asked a long time ago in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088557/download-github-raw-source-file-by-url
however the token now seems to change daily and is different for each file.

The other method I could use would be to directly use the api...however the content is that is downloaded is often encoded in bas64 and due to the original having some "special characters" its is difficult to decode...or it doesn't always decode correctly.

I am currently using httr to access the github api...but do not seem to be able to access the actual content of the individual files/(not a whole package) i want to download...

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in this [GitHub project](https://github.com/lbdremy/gedit-jade), you don't need the token for public repos.

```
wget https://raw.github.com/lbdremy/gedit-jade/master/jade.lang -O ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/jade.lang
```

Plus, with GitHub APIV3, Basic auth with tokens is not supported (see "[GitHub API: Moving On](https://github.com/blog/1090-github-api-moving-on)").